# Make String add with hyperlink in react-native?

Tags: string, react-native, hyperlink

I want to make my string clickable and add hyperlink to string. so wherever display my string is clickable. any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

The Text component in React Native have a onPress as one of its props. You can use it to handle the clicking action.

```
<Text onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('https://google.com')}>My Text</Text>
```

source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text#onpress

Comment: I don't need <Text> or button I want link hidden inside string. like this <p><a href="http://jsdf.co">&hearts; nice job!</a></p>. but this need html parser

Comment: The code isn't for a button, if you run it in a react native app, it will only show "My Text" and can be clicked to open the URL

Comment: I want to send link in chat dynamically not need of <Text>. suppose half of text come from response is clickable and half is not. then ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the react-native-parsed-text library.

Example:

```
import ParsedText from 'react-native-parsed-text';

class Example extends React.Component {
  static displayName = 'Example';

  handleUrlPress(url) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ParsedText
          style={styles.text}
          parse={
            [
              {type: 'url',                       style: styles.url, onPress: this.handleUrlPress},
            ]
          }
          childrenProps={{allowFontScaling: false}}
        >
          My text with URL here
        </ParsedText>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },

  url: {
    color: 'red',
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },

});
```

Here is a link of the library documentation: https://github.com/taskrabbit/react-native-parsed-text